# DAO package structure

Tags: java, dao

I'm writing some simple DAOs in Java using JDBC (no Spring, Hibernate or anything else).

Is it better to put the implementation DAOs in the same package as their interfaces or to put them in a sub-package?

Example:

```
com.mycompany.myproject.dao.MyDao
com.mycompany.myproject.dao.MyDaoImpl
```

OR

```
com.mycompany.myproject.dao.MyDao
com.mycompany.myproject.dao.impl.MyDaoImpl
```

If you suggest the sub-package structure, what would you suggest as a sub-package name?  .impl?  .sql?  .jdbc?

Realistically, I'm not going to have multiple implementations.  Am I over-engineering this?

Comment: No alternate implementations at all? Not even unit test mocks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When designing an application there is no *standard* way of structuring in packages, experience is what usually helps every one to decide what are the appropriate names for our packages.

About packaging implementations of your interfaces in the same package or in a different one just think about how Java itself is structured: usually an implementation class is packaged in the same package that its interface, but is not all the times.

If you were about to have several implementations of the same DAO's then it would make sense having them structured in `.jdbc`, `.jpa` or `.jdo` sub packages. If your are only going to have one implementation both of the options you enumerate make sense in some way (same package or a `.impl` sub package).

Regarding over-engineering I would recommend you this [article](http://marekdec.wordpress.com/2011/12/06/explicit-interface-per-class-antipattern/). Even though you are going to have just one implementation of your DAO's, it would make sense to have them defined as an interface and implementation as that will help you in a potential future to rewrite your DAOs for other frameworks whilst the code that makes use of them keeps unchanged.

At the end it's up to you (or you and your peers) to reach a consensus and make the decision that makes more sense in your specific case.

**EDIT**

An application usually has one implementation per DAO interface and that isn't over-engineering at all, it simply doesn't make sense to have the same DAO interface implemented for JPA and for JDO. Some of the purposes of using the interface/implementation pattern is to ease re-factoring, testing by means of mock objects, etc..

P.S.: I usually rely on [JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) to distribute my application classes in packages avoiding cycles as most as I can.

Comment: The standard way is to separate it out. Any architect would point you to the problems you face by keeping them in the same package. Eventually, your code will get very fat and indivisible without you realising it. It all looks small when you code but one should code keeping the scaling and management in mind for the future.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I consider this answer nowadays quite outdated and, in all honestly, I would never organize the code how the OP, this answer, or you are suggesting since all of those are ignoring cohesion and modularity of functional pieces, regarless of the fact each module may use JDO, or DynamoDB independently of each other. That's the actual problem behind making code divisible, and not putting the socks of the same colour into the same drawer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think either is *better*, but in this case I prefer the first alternative. It would be in line with having `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc. , in the same package as  `List`.

When using additional frameworks, such as `hibernate` I prefer the second option with `MyDao` and `HibernateDao` as the implementor.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with your second option (although none is really better), because you can see immediately in your imports if an impl is imported and refactoring would be simpler if you want to move your impl in another project.

This is not over-engineering. There are multiple advantages to use DAO:

1. It improves the quality of your code by decoupling database access from other considerations
2. Testing your code is made easier and you can test it with a finer grain.
3. If some day, you find out that Hibernate is actually a lot easier for you, it won't impact the rest of your code.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is not only from code point of view that we should think but also packaging point of view. We are currently converting our monolith to microservices and the biggest problem we face is that both interface and implementing classes have been put in the same package. Using some tools on internet, you can check how fat your entire project has gotten by not separating out these things in the begining itself.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces and packages only exist to prevent collisions. Neither is preferable as long as they are unique.

Comment: So it's okay just to name your packages long, random strings of characters? Sensible package names make it easier for people to navigate your API and can make refactoring easier. Also, separation of e.g. implementation and interface is good practice in environments where exports and dependencies are specified by the package, as you will often only want to depend on either interface or implementation.

Comment: My answer was specific to OP's case. There is no objective difference between his/her proposed alternatives. In regards to your comment I can only say creating a comprehensible namespace is common sense.

Answer (score 0):

One purpose of packages is to improve readability for the other programmers on your team. Generally, I put the implementation in the same package as the interface, because that is the obvious place to look, and in most cases, the DAO implementation is simple. If your implementation is complex, then you should find a framework that is appropriate for your application.

Other reasons to consider a separate package include: if you are writing a library that will be used by other groups, or if you want to support multiple implementations.